# Which socket is gnome-shell reading from continuously?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, socket, file-descriptors

`strace` shows that the GNOME shell is continuously trying to read from a socket, 
which is often not available (or doesn't contain any data to read from):

```
strace -p gnome-shell-pid -e trace=recvfrom

recvfrom(6, 0x1390a84, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(6, 0x1390a84, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(6, "\1\233t\35\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\3304\351\244\307\202\36", 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 32
recvfrom(6, 0x1390a84, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(6, 0x1390a84, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(6, 0x1390a84, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(6, 0x1390a84, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(6, 0x1390a84, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(6, 0x1390a84, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(6, 0x1390a84, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

`/proc/$pid/fd` shows that *6* is a file descriptor for a UNIX socket.

```
lrwx------. 1 me me 64 Jan  5 12:48 6 -> socket:[55696]
```

I tried to get info about that in `/proc/$pid/net/unix`, but it seems that this file doesn't contain any useful information for this purpose.

Is it possible to know which process is on the other side of this connection?

**Edit:**
output of `lsof | grep 55696`:

```
gnome-she  2250         hamid    6u     unix 0xffff880101064000       0t0      55696 socket
gdbus      2250  5801   hamid    6u     unix 0xffff880101064000       0t0      55696 socket
dconf      2250  5805   hamid    6u     unix 0xffff880101064000       0t0      55696 socket
threaded-  2250  5806   hamid    6u     unix 0xffff880101064000       0t0      55696 socket
JS         2250  5807   hamid    6u     unix 0xffff880101064000       0t0      55696 socket
JS         2250  5808   hamid    6u     unix 0xffff880101064000       0t0      55696 socket
gmain      2250  5818   hamid    6u     unix 0xffff880101064000       0t0      55696 socket
```

This means that this socket is used by threads of the GNOME shell process. OK, but can anyone say what data is sent and received by this socket?

Comment: Does `lsof|grep 55696` show anything?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes. Please see the edit. Thanks